# IE9 not accepting standard jQuery Syntax

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, html, internet-explorer-9

It's really pretty simple. I have the following code.. and it works in every other html5 compatible browser (Safari 5, Chrome 9, FireFox), but in IE9 (RC) I get the following errors.

### jquery.min.js

> Line: 16
>   Error: Object doesn't support property or method 'getElementsByTagName'

### jquery-ui.min.js

> Line: 40
>   Error: Object doesn't support property or method 'tabs'

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.10/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("#ribbon").tabs();
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <span id="branding"></span>
        <div id="ribbon-navigation">
        <div id="ribbon">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#ribbon-1">1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#ribbon-2">2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#ribbon-3">3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#ribbon-4">4</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="ribbon-1" class="ribbon-strip">
        @Html.Partial("Menus/Ribbons/__H1")
    </div>
    <div id="ribbon-2" class="ribbon-strip">
        @Html.Partial("Menus/Ribbons/__2")
    </div>
    <div id="ribbon-3" class="ribbon-strip">
        @Html.Partial("Menus/Ribbons/__3")
    </div>
    <div id="ribbon-4" class="ribbon-strip">
        @Html.Partial("Menus/Ribbons/__4")
    </div>
</div>
        </div>
    </header>
</body>
</html>
```

I could understand if my CSS just didn't produce the right styles - but it looks like it's outright ignoring `$("#ribbon").tabs();` all together. Any ideas?

Comment: Could you run it with the non-minified libraries, and let us know what the line numbers are for the errors?

Comment: As per endophage's answer below - your construct is executing the javascript code at that very moment, before the rest of the page has loaded and the `<div id="ribbon">` hasn't been parsed yet. Using the `ready()` function will "pause" your script until the page's DOM has finished building.

Comment: Actually I have discovered the error. Further digging yielded more fruitful results... http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/8052 - This is apparently a bug in IE, and was fixed in an update of jQuery that came out _Yesterday_ of all times! I had to reference jQuery 1.5.1, and it all worked fine.

Comment: What should I do? I answered my own question, but others might find this useful. How do I close the question appropriately? Just click the `close` button?

Comment: @Marc B: OP *is* using the `.ready()` method. Doing `$(function(){...})` is a shortcut for it.

Comment: @Stacey: You should post an answer giving the solution.

Comment: @Stacey - It's appropriate to add your own answer and accept it (Ahh - patrick beat me to it :) ).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Further digging yielded more fruitful results... bugs.jquery.com/ticket/8052 - This is apparently a bug in IE, and was fixed in an update of jQuery that came out Yesterday of all times! I had to reference jQuery 1.5.1, and it all worked fine.

Thank you to everyone who jumped in with helpful suggestions. They were all very good ideas, but this time it turned out to simply be a bug with IE9 and nothing more.

Comment: I just experienced this problem and 1.5.1 did fix the IE9 problem. Does anyone know up there is a newer version than 1.5.1 that works with IE9 ?

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#ribbon").tabs();
});
```

Comment: The method `tabs` appears to be called (or attempted), so I think the DOM ready function is working.

Comment: `$(document).ready(handler)` is the same as `$(handler)` - http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: If you mean it was working without the `.ready` it would get called anyway.  It's saying the object doesn't support the property or method, probably because the div with `id="ribbon"` doesn't exist yet so null is being returned from `$("#ribbon")`

Comment: @Jonathon Bolster They say that... I've never managed to get that to work...  Admittedly I haven't tried in a long time because I just got into the habit of doing `$(document).ready()`.

Comment: Endophage: As @Jonathon noted, OP is using a shortcut for `.ready()`. jQuery methods don't give an Error when no DOM elements are matched. They just fail silently.

Comment: @patrick dw Note my previous comment on the shortcut.  I agree that the `$('#ribbon')` would fail silently but `.tabs()` is what is failing noisily.

Comment: That's odd that you haven't gotten it to work. Maybe you were using an older version of jQuery? Anyway, my original point was that if the shortcut version wasn't working, the code inside would't be invoked, and and there couldn't be an error pointing to `tabs`. Then again, stranger things have happened. :o)

Comment: @patrick dw actually, the code inside would still be invoked because the $() syntax is still correct.  It would attempt to invoke the code inside $() before every trying to invoke $() unless there was some other syntactic error.

Comment: @Endophage: Yes, but if the `$(function(){...` syntax is correct, then you're not gaining anything by replacing it with `$(document).ready(function(){...`. But if `$(function(){...` is not correct (or not working), then the code inside it won't be invoked and you won't get the `tabs` error. That was the original point I was trying to make.

Comment: @patrick dw I'm saying the `$()` syntax is correct regardless of whether it's used as a shortcut to `.ready` or as a selector.  I'm guessing it evaluates passed parameters to work out whether it's a function or selector string so maybe that syntax is working as the shortcut.  You may be right.  Either way, I've still had fewer problems with using `$(document).ready()`.

Comment: Yes, it does duck-typing to figure out what to do. My original point was that the handler was firing, so suggesting `$(document).ready()` was probably not a solution to the issue OP was having.